# how to see the dump() message in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm currently developing a firefox extension. I use `dump()` function. But the messages are not showing up in the console. I've cahnged the value of `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` to `true` in `about:config` and restarted firefox from command linelike `firefox.exe -console`. Still i cant see the `dump()` message. What is possibly wrong?

Btw, Is there any addon which can show the `dump()` messages without having to restart firefox in command line `firefox -console`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this addon to be really helpful when logging errors/messages to the console: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/

Answer (score 1):

Starting Firefox with `-console` command line switch is only necessary on Windows. If you are using Linux then you should simply start Firefox from a terminal window. On Mac OS X the console messages can be displayed via some application (sorry, don't remember which one). Also, changing `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` is only necessary if you are logging from a window-bound context - in JavaScript modules and such it always works regardless of this preference.

If you want to have your logging messages available more easily you should be using [`Components.utils.reportError()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.reportError) (or `nsIConsoleService.logStringMessage()` as explained in the documentation) - this will send messages to the usual Error Console that can be opened at any time.

Comment: Wow so i finally found out thats how you view `dump` messages. I just started using `ChromeWorker`s and couldn't use the awesome `console.log`. But the console window is soooo bad, things are cut off, you cant scroll etc etc. Is there any alternative to `dump` from `ChromeWorker`? I know of `throw` but that interrupts the code.

Answer (score 0):

To finally get the output from dump(), I specified dump file location by creating a preference `browser.dom.window.dump.file` and setting it in **about:config**.

I believe I had the same issue. I couldn't get dump() to print to stderr nor the console even though I had set `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` to `true`. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.dom.window.dump.file