# Using dll in js-ctypes mozilla add-on sdk - view program's STDOUT?

Tags: javascript, dll, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

Edited because I had the DLL built wrong:

I have built a DLL, and if I do a `dumpbin /exports` command on the DLL I see the following:

```
Dump of file stun_driver.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for stun_driver.dll

00000000 characteristics
546E6C63 time date stamp Thu Nov 20 17:34:11 2014
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
       4 number of functions
       4 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001005 OPENSSL_Applink = @ILT+0(_OPENSSL_Applink)
      2    1 00001320 launch_stun = @ILT+795(_launch_stun)
      3    2 000011D6 stop_stun = @ILT+465(_stop_stun)
      4    3 00001078 test_print = @ILT+115(_test_print)

  Summary

   1A000 .data
    2000 .idata
   46000 .rdata
    F000 .reloc
  135000 .text
```

My code for executing the "test_print" function, is as follows:

```
/* import js-ctypes */
 Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm")
 var stun_driver = ctypes.open("C:\\stun_driver.dll");

const test_print = stun_driver.declare("test_print", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int32_t);
.
.
.//in a button
test_print();
```

So my question is, if my `test_print()` is doing a `printf("Hello World")`, where does that text go? It doesn't seem to be getting logged to my browser console, or to the dos console i am running "cfx run" from.

Comment: A nice topic on this subject: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1086/x11-getting-output-of-nsiprocess/?answer=1116#post-id-1116

Comment: Hrmm. It seems like that is talking about running shell commands from the add-on, as opposed to running methods in a shared library - or am I mistaken?

Comment: You're right. To get the output of the dll you have to use shell to run it and then get the output of shell. Check out subprocess.jsm.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://mar10.noblogs.org/post/2014/10/02/loading-a-native-library-in-firefox-via-the-add-ons-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

If you start Firefox from a terminal window, you *should* see the output there.

Comment: I can see the output in that terminal window from the javascript console.log() and such, but I don't seem to see any output from my C program

Comment: @Derek i think you have to start firefox with -console command line option see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10793558/1828637 (i think this is windows only)

Comment: Interestingly enough - if I use https://github.com/matthewkastor/Redirector/archive/master.zip and launch firefox using that, I can get console output. I just discovered `cfx` has an option `--binary-args` that I can use to pass `-console` to firefox. This makes a terminal come up with firefox, and but gets no output. However, if I close that blank terminal (which shuts off firefox), I see the output show up in the original terminal with my `cfx run` in it