# Javascripts Dump() is not defined

Tags: javascript

Was just looking around [MDN about `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) and the example that they had given was:

> ```
> dump(document.location);
> // Prints a string like
> // "http://www.example.com/juicybits.html" to the console
> ```

So I open up my console and type in `dump(document.location)` and all I keep getting is `dump is not defined`. I even tried `window.dump(document.location)`.

I then proceeded to look at the API for dump on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/dump) but it seemed like I was using it properly.

I also tried it in Firefox - but still kept getting `undefined` So I then tried enabling it with `window.dump.enabled` - but that didn't do anything for me either.

Here is a screen cap of my Mozilla console:

[image]

What could I be missing here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/dump and dump.enabled I suppose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793460/how-to-see-the-dump-message-in-firefox

Comment: "*You can set the preference in about:config or 
in a user.js file.*" Not from the console of course.

Comment: @Bergi well there's your problem. So I switched it - went to a website and did `dump(window.location)` and I still got `undefined`?

Comment: What do you mean by "went to a website"?

Comment: @DaveNewton Just went to any website - like www.stackoverflow.com, opened up the console and tried `dump(window.location)`

Comment: @Adjit How is that "not from the console"?

Comment: @DaveNewton Bergi was talking about setting up the preferences to enable dump. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to call it from the console.

Comment: @Adjit You *can*. You *are*.

Comment: @Adjit: So what? The function is defined and returns `undefined` (instead of throwing a type error that there is no such function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says right in the docs you link to (emphasis mine):

> A common use of `dump()` is to debug JavaScript. **The message passed to `dump()` is sent to the System Console (Native Console) if the Firefox proces was started withe the -console option**. If the -console option was not specified then the output goes to stderr. **Output from `dump()` is not sent to the Browser Console.** Output can be sent to the Browser Console using `console.log()`. Privileged code can also use `Components.utils.reportError` and `nsIConsoleService` to log messages to the Error Console/Browser Console.

You can't enable it and have it do something other than what it says it'll do, you need to look in the correct place for output, which isn't the browser console, rather where the docs say.

You *can* call it from the console, and *are*. It returns `undefined`, just like `console.log`.

Type in `dump`:

```
[16:40:57.545] dump
[16:40:57.547] [object Function]
```

It's defined.

Comment: Ok yeah, I had read all of that - I completely forgot about functions returning undefined. I don't know why I was thinking it was saying the function is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It's a firefox(mozilla)-specific function.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - but then when I tried it in firefox I just kept getting `undefined`

Comment: I also tried enabling it with `window.dump.enabled` but that also returns `undefined`

Comment: @Adjit I have no idea - I was answering the original question why it's not defined.

Comment: @Adjit Did you try `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` as per the docs?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I did. posted a screen-cap of my console.